# Emacs, Linux and international keyboard layouts

Tags: linux, emacs, internationalization, keyboard

Is there an easy way to use Emacs key-bindings when you are using a not-English (Russian) keyboard layout?

Whenever an international layout is on, all keystrokes are interpreted literally, M-ф instead of M-a. As a result I can't use commands.

It would also be nice if Linux could interpret non-prefixed and shift-prefixed keys according according to an international layout, while keeping the rest English.

Comment: One way is to use English layout while you are on Emacs.. if you want write Russian in emacs change emacs input method by pressing `C-\ `

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set input method (kudos go to *kindahero*) by typing

```
M-x set-input-method RET cyrillic-yawerty RET
```

or

```
M-x set-input-method RET cyrillic-jcuken RET
```

---

To store it permanently, add

```
(setq default-input-method "cyrillic-yawerty")
```

to *~/.emacs* config (and use <kbd>C-\</kbd> to switch between keyboard layouts).

Comment: You mean M-x set-input-method, and then C-\ to switch between Russian and English? At least that's what worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative solution that uses the OS language, based on syndikat's answer.

Some key translations are missing, but it should be easy to add them.

```lisp
;; USAGE:
;; Put in your .emacs:
;; 
;; (translate-keystrokes-ru->en)
;; (add-hook 'text-mode-hook
;;           (lambda () (literal-insert-mode 1)))
;; 
;; Only buffers with literal-insert-mode active will be sensitive to the
;; environment language. Prefixed keybindings will still be usable.

(defun translate-keystrokes-ru->en ()
  "Make emacs output english characters, regardless whether
the OS keyboard is english or russian"
  (flet ((make-key-stroke (prefix char)
           (eval `(kbd ,(if (and (string-match "^C-" prefix)
                                 (string-match "[A-Z]" (string char)))
                            (concat "S-" prefix (string (downcase char)))
                            (concat prefix (string char)))))))
    (let ((case-fold-search nil)
          (keys-pairs (mapcar* 'cons
                               "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖ\ЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ№"
                               "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>#"))
          (prefixes '(""    "s-"    "M-"    "M-s-"
                      "C-"  "C-s-"  "C-M-"  "C-M-s-")))
      (mapc (lambda (prefix)
              (mapc (lambda (pair)
                      (define-key key-translation-map
                          (make-key-stroke prefix (car pair))
                        (make-key-stroke prefix (cdr pair))))
                    keys-pairs))
            prefixes))))

(defun literal-insert ()
  (interactive)
  (insert-char last-input-event 1))

(define-minor-mode literal-insert-mode
    "Make emacs output characters corresponging to the OS keyboard,
 ignoring the key-translation-map"
  :keymap (let ((new-map (make-sparse-keymap))
                (english-chars "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>#"))
            (mapc (lambda (char)
                    (define-key new-map (string char)
                      'literal-insert))
                  english-chars)
            new-map))
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, where did [sabof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/735243/sabof) got 150 billion. I ran this code (thanks to Yuri Khan, taken from [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnuEmacsRussification)):

```lisp
(loop
 for from across "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖ\ЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ№"
 for to   across "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>#"
 do
 (eval `(define-key key-translation-map (kbd ,(concat "C-" (string from))) (kbd ,(concat     "C-" (string to)))))
 (eval `(define-key key-translation-map (kbd ,(concat "M-" (string from))) (kbd ,(concat     "M-" (string to))))))
```

It's only 128 combinations. Unfortunately, combinations with single letters like <kbd>C-x b</kbd> don't work. I'm still trying to find a better solution.

Comment: This means you didn't understand my comment. I've added an improved version as an answer, in case someone needs it

Comment: It seems you can make <kbd>C-x b</kbd> combinations with something like 
`(loop
 for from across "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖ\ЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ№"
 for to   across "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>#"
 do
 (global-set-key (kbd (concat "C-x " (string from))) (key-binding (kbd (concat "C-x " (string to))) t))
 )`


`

Answer (score 1):

I use following snippet for Cyrillic keyboard and it works fine for me:

```
(defun reverse-input-method (input-method)
  "Build the reverse mapping of single letters from INPUT-METHOD."
  (interactive
   (list (read-input-method-name "Use input method (default current): ")))
  (if (and input-method (symbolp input-method))
      (setq input-method (symbol-name input-method)))
  (let ((current current-input-method)
        (modifiers '(nil (control) (meta) (control meta))))
    (when input-method
      (activate-input-method input-method))
    (when (and current-input-method quail-keyboard-layout)
      (dolist (map (cdr (quail-map)))
        (let* ((to (car map))
               (from (quail-get-translation
                      (cadr map) (char-to-string to) 1)))
          (when (and (characterp from) (characterp to))
            (dolist (mod modifiers)
              (define-key local-function-key-map
                (vector (append mod (list from)))
                (vector (append mod (list to)))))))))
    (when input-method
      (activate-input-method current))))

(reverse-input-method 'russian-computer)
```

Except:

> The only issue I know is that recalculation of OrgTable formulas isn't
>   working in Russian layout because it is mapped to C-c-* and * change
>   its location.

[source](https://www.alexkorablev.com/emacs-got-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the Russian layout in Emacs (rather than use Emacs's own input methods), the only way I know of for now is to add bindings of the form:

```
(define-key function-key-map [?\M-ф] [?\M-a])
```

This will tell Emacs that in case M-ф is not bound, it should try to lookup M-a instead.  Sadly, you'll need a lot of these bindings.  If someone writes up a patch/package that can automatically provide all these bindings, I'd be happy to include it in Emacs.

Comment: I did a rough calculation and end up with 150 billion combinations, assuming 4 modifier keys, a 4-long chord, and 40 keys. A on-the-fly translator function might be nicer

Comment: I've written a snippet that takes care of the bindings. It's half-cooked - it could take maps from mule to provide bindings for all keyboards. It also conflicts with modes that override the self-insert command, such as cua-rectangle.

Comment: @sabof: whilte the number of combinations needed to cover all cases is large, it's not quite as large as you think because this remapping is applied *within* key sequences.  So the single example I showed will already cover `C-x M-ф` or `M-ф M-ф` for example.  But yes, 40-keys combined with 4 modifiers gives you 480 bindings and clearly doing it programmatically on-the-fly would be much better.