# Emacs With GUI on mac os. Different keyboard layout key bindings

Tags: macos, emacs

I am using two version of emacs. One in terminal, and other from [emacsformacosx.com](http://emacsformacosx.com). In terminal I can use non-English keyboard layout and everything fine. But emacs version with gui don't understands these commands. Why it happening? Why I can't just run terminal version with GUI?

update:
For example when I pressed M-x with non-English keyboard layout in minibuffer appear text - M-ч is undefined. ч is a symbol equal to x. Pressing same shortcut in terminal version of Emacs works fine. Emacs running on other OS haven't this problem. I think to solve it needs to run terminal version with gui and use it. It is impossible. But why?

Comment: Are you actually running two different versions of Emacs? What does `M-x version` give in each one?

Comment: Terminal version - 
GNU EMACS 22.1.1 (mac-apple-darwin) of 2014-04-18 on osx102.apple.com
Emacs gui - 
GNU EMACS 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) of 2013-03-13 on bob.parking.org

Comment: Okay, so you're running two very different versions of Emacs. Not sure what the problem is (you'll need to add much more detail to your question, e.g. what keys are you pressing, what do you expect to happen, what actually does happen?), but you may want to consider only using Emacs 24. It is much improved from Emacs 22.

Comment: I added some update. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: As a workaround, can't you just `(global-set-key "\M-ч" 'execute-extended-command)`?

Comment: I suspect that the emacsformacosx build simply has not been built to this requirement. Maybe file a bug report with the maintainer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs, Linux and international keyboard layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639429/emacs-linux-and-international-keyboard-layouts)